# firebase phone number authentication :java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: android, flutter

```
W/System  (11606): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
E/FirebaseAuth(11606): [GetAuthDomainTask] IOException occurred: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
E/zzf     (11606): Failed to get reCAPTCHA token with error [An internal error has occurred.]- calling backend without app verification
W/System  (11606): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
E/FirebaseAuth(11606): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17499 java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException:Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

I am getting this error while running flutter app using emulator. Tried everything like adding sha256. Sha1 enable safety net. Everything. I think issue with this machine.

Comment: any one found solution for this issue then pls share with us

Comment: Mine problem was VPN, please check your network and thn try.

Comment: you have to add SSL certificate in your app raw folder also create network_security_config file and connect with android manifest file

Comment: how did u know this was VPN fault and how did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

here is your network_security_config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/cert" />
        </trust-anchors>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">xyz.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

also link with android manifest file like

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

also you need **cert.pem** file put it on your **raw** folder and it will working in all devices

Comment: I followed it but now it doesn't compile anymore, with this error: 'network_security_config' is incompatible with attribute networkSecurityConfig

Comment: cani u pls send me the error ?

Comment: you have to replace your domain name with xyz.com

Comment: and you can download cert.perm file from google chrome